# Rails-DoubleRenderError. Why redirected Twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

When I hit the download link for the second time, an error occurred.

This is the log file:

> AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".)

After I added "and return" after the `redirect_to` function, the code works.

I don't get it. There is no code after `redirect_to`. Shouldn't the action terminate after the redirection?

```
class StatisticsController < ApplicationController
      def getForms
        unless File.exists? "public/downloads/#{session[ "yearSelected" ]}.csv"
          # Database Aggregation 
          new_students = {}
          new_students[ "CP" ] = Student.where([ "first_tamu_term like ? and prim_deg_maj_1 like ? and prim_deg like ?", session[ "yearSelected" ]+"%", "CP%", "M%" ]).count
          new_students[ "CE" ] = Student.where([ "first_tamu_term like ? and prim_deg_maj_1 like ? and prim_deg like ?", session[ "yearSelected" ]+"%", "CE%", "M%" ]).count

          prior_students = {}
          prior_students[ "CP" ] = Student.where([ "first_tamu_term like ? and prim_deg_maj_1 like ? and prim_deg like ?", (session[ "yearSelected" ].to_i-1).to_s+"%", "CP%", "M%" ]).count
          prior_students[ "CE" ] = Student.where([ "first_tamu_term like ? and prim_deg_maj_1 like ? and prim_deg like ?", (session[ "yearSelected" ].to_i-1).to_s+"%", "CE%", "M%" ]).count

          # Generate .csv file containing all the statistics
          CSV.open("public/downloads/#{session[ "yearSelected" ]}.csv", "wb") do |csv|
            csv << ["", "CS", "CE"]
            csv << ["Number of newly-admitted masters students", new_students[ "CP" ].to_s, new_students[ "CE" ].to_s]
            csv << ["Prior Year", prior_students[ "CP" ].to_s, prior_students[ "CE" ].to_s]
          end
        end

        @file_names = {:form1 => "The form for the number of masters students in #{session[ "yearSelected" ]}"}

        # render the page of downloading links
      end

      def getForm1
        Thread.new do
          send_file "public/downloads/#{session[ "yearSelected" ]}.csv", type: 'text/csv'
        end

        redirect_to statistics_getForms_path and return
      end
    end
```

getForms.html.haml:

```
%html
  %head
    %title Taulbee survey Statistics
    :css
      .heading{
        color:white;
        background-color:#500000;
        height:50px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        font-size:40px;
      }

      .centered{
        text-align:center;
      }

  %body
    %h1.centered.heading Taulbee Survey
    %p
      %a{:id => "Home", :href => site_index_path}
        %img{:height => "30", :src => "/images/homepageicon.jpg", :width => "30"}/
      %a{:id => "Back", :href => site_studentFilterSelection_path}
        %img{:height => "30", :src => "/images/previous-icon.png", :width => "30"}/

    = link_to @file_names[ :form1 ], statistics_getForm1_path
```

Comment: seems like there is a `redirect_to` or `render` defined on your `send_file` method definition

Comment: You mean sending files are actually doing a redirection? Or what do you mean?